# How to insert each line of a Textbox lines to a database (line by line) using a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach

I want to insert each line of a `Textbox` lines to a row of database (line by line) when its `TextMode` property is `Multiline` using a `foreach` loop? I used this code but it inserts all the lines in one row of my "ChTB" table. What is wrong with it?

```
string ID = null;
DateTime RegDtTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ChTB";
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con1);
con1.Open();
foreach (object line_loopVariable in this.Textbox1.Text.Split({ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)) {
    line = line_loopVariable;
    ID = line;
    string commandText = "insert into ChTB(ID,Visible,RegDtTime,LastDateTime) values(@ID,@Visible,@RegDtTime,@LastDateTime)";
    SqlCommand cmdObj = new SqlCommand(commandText, con1);
    cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visible", "NO");
    cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDtTime", RegDtTime);
    cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastDateTime", RegDtTime);
    cmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con1.Close();
```

Comment: Test the length of your text by MsgBox(Me.Textbox1.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length). If it returns 1, then maybe your text does not contain whatever the current setting of Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using three different variables for the same value?  Just do this:

```
foreach (var line in myTextBox.Lines)
{
    // Use line here.
}
```

As for the insert, don't create a new command object every time and add new parameters.  Create one object, add the parameters and then set their `Value` properties each time, e.g.

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (SomeColumn) VALUES (@SomeColumn)", connection)
var parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@SomeColumn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)

foreach (var line in myTextBox.Lines)
{
    parameter.Value = line

    // Execute command here.
}
```